# Why can't we just say 1 instead of "unity"?

Tags: terminology, roots-of-unity

I know this is a soft question of sorts but I am curious why we can't just say "1" instead of "unity," e.g. a root of unity.

Comment: ... the concept extends to any algebraic *unital* ring.

Comment: @oldrinb: but that doesn't explain anything, since rings also have the concept of "unit", which means something quite different, making "unity" even more confusing!

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh unit may refer to either an element with a multiplicative inverse in some contexts, but in the context of a unital ring it refers to the multiplicative identity.

Comment: Why the downvote O_O

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh in case of ambiguity, typically the multiplicative identity is referred to as *unity*.

Comment: @oldrinb: (second comment) I disagree. Wikipedia sez: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh out of curiosity did you manage to read past the first two paragraphs? "*Unfortunately, the term unit is also used to refer to the identity element $1_R$ of the ring, in expressions like ring with a unit or unit ring, and also e.g. 'unit' matrix. (For this reason, some authors call $1_R$ "unity" or "identity", and say that $R$ is a "ring with unity" or a "ring with identity" rather than a "ring with a unit".)*"

Comment: @oldrinb: Well, I read your second comment as saying that in a unital ring, the word _unit_  **only** means _multiplicative identity_. In any case, I think this proves that the term "unity" is confusing!

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh yes indeed it is! :-) I figured "one" seems like a less general term than *unity*, so naming them roots of unity seems more broad a term (or a historical artifact). I apologize for my lack of clarity; I meant the term *unit* in *unital* (as in *unital ring*) refers to the multiplicative identity.

Comment: And, for those folks who *are* comfortable writing "ring with $1$" for "ring with unit(y)", why not also write "$0$-divisor" vs. "zero-divisor"?

Comment: @oldrinb: I get your meaning now! My two cents: I think people prefer "unity" because saying "a ring with one" sounds incomplete: the instinctive response is, "a ring with one what?"

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I agree, it does sound strange... and like your previous comment pointed out, prone to confusion.

Comment: A unital ring (with invertible elements) is a ring with unity anyway so at least there is no ambiguity for the term 'unital ring', whatever you mean by 'unit'.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We can.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How did you avoid the "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 7."?

Comment: Never mind I found out. $\$\{\}\{\}\{\}\{\}\{\}\{\}\$$

Comment: Now, we know ${}{}{}$

Comment: Sneaky. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: All you need is a "Yes"in front of this answer, and you can win the U.S. elections!

Comment: @Asaf: If only that didn't strike uncomfortably close to the truth....